# In QT using QFileDialog's getExistingDirectory, how can I start in a directory specified by an environment variable?

Tags: c++, qt

In QT using QFileDialog's getExistingDirectory, how can I start in a directory specified by an environment variable?

That is to say, how can I do this:

```
return QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, "Open Directory", "%HOME%", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
```

Where %HOME% is the Windows Envirnment Variable to the user's home usually found in C:\Users\UserName

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would probably be:

```
return QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, "Open Directory", getenv("HOME"), QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
```

`getenv` is declared in `stdlib.h`

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for asking such a simple question.

Comment: There is also qgetenv() in Qt "because getenv() from the standard C library was deprecated in VC2005 (and later versions)."

Comment: Qt has also another way of getting these standard folders which for `%HOME%` is `QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::HomeLocation)`.